# getting document is not defined error in Angular SSR while using jsPlumb & @jsplumb/browser-ui with third-party library

Tags: typescript, angular11, jsplumb

getting document is not defined error in Angular SSR while using jsPlumb & @jsplumb/browser-ui with third-party library

When we start running with npm run build:ssr, there is no issues with the build, but when i run npm run serve:ssr i am getting error as "document is not defined"

This is my package.json file:

````
  "name": "newadmin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config ../proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run newadmin:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/newadmin/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run newadmin:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run newadmin:prerender",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/localize": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.1",
    "@jsplumb/browser-ui": "^5.0.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.3",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^11.2.1",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.2.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1022.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bowser": "^2.11.0",
    "drawflow": "0.0.52",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.1.4",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.1",
    "jsplumb": "2.15.6",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "material-icons": "^1.10.1",
    "ng-otp-input": "^1.8.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.1.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^11.0.2",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-linkifyjs": "^1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "strophe.js": "^1.4.2",
    "tinymce": "^5.10.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.15",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.1",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^11.2.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.36",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.2"
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are also importing jsPlumb 2.15.6. You should remove that dependency.

Comment: we also tried without jsPlumb 2.15.6 and only with @jsplumb/browser-ui, but also getting same error as "document is not defined" (in SSR only)

is jsplumb and @jslumb/browser-ui will work in SSR or NOT ?

for Angular 11 version which is suitable jsplumb or @jsplumb/browser-ui ? and can you suggest any proper documentation

Comment: I see, right.  Well 'jsplumb', as in 2.x, expects a browser.  And for 5.x the name `browser-ui` references the fact that it's intended to run in a browser.

Comment: How to run ```browser-ui``` in @angular/universal (Angular SSR)?
because i am still getting ```document is not defined``` error.

is these packages suitable for Angular 11 version (SSR)?